# Is there a simple group that is torsion-free, type $\textrm{F}_\infty$, and infinite dimensional?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Does there exist an example of a group that is:

1. Simple,
2. Torsion-free,
3. Of type $\textrm{F}_\infty$, and
4. Infinite dimensional (meaning of infinite cohomological dimension)?

Thompson's group $F$ has all these properties except not (1). Thompson's groups $T$ and $V$ have all these properties except not (2). The commutator subgroup $[F,F]$ has all these properties except not (3). My understanding is that things like Burger-Mozes groups have all these properties except not (4).

I'm curious whether there is an example with all four properties. Many "Thompson-like" constructions provide examples of groups with properties (3) and (4), but any of the examples I can think of only have one of property (1) or (2), not both. It's possible this question is just open, but outside the "Thompson world" I don't know much about infinite simple groups, so I may be missing something.

Comment: A silly and trivial comment: there's no need for $T$ and $V$ to get all but 2 -- any finite simple group will do the trick.

Comment: Ha, good point Andy!

Comment: But finite groups are have cohomological dimension zero over $\mathbf{Q}$, so $F$, $T$ and $V$ satisfy (4) in a stronger sense.

Comment: True, and another natural strengthening of (4) that keeps all the examples relevant would be, "contains free abelian groups of arbitrarily large rank" (maybe this could be called "infinite algebraic dimension" or something).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A while ago, James Hyde and Yash Lodha found a group with all four of these properties, I should mention this here. The paper is https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.04805 (to appear in Ann. Sci. Ecole Normale Sup.). The group is not only torsion-free, but left-orderable. They actually found an infinite family of examples, but let me explain the easiest one.

Take the group of all piecewise-linear, orientation-preserving homeomorphisms $f$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that have breakpoints in $\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ and slopes of the form $2^i 3^j$, commute with translation by 1, and also satisfy that if the slope of $f$ at $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ is $2^i 3^j$ then the difference $i-j$ equals the (signed) number of integers strictly in between $x$ and $x.f$.

They prove that the commutator subgroup of this group is simple and of type $\mathrm{F}_\infty$, hence satisfies properties (1) and (3), and obviously satisfies (2) and (4) since it's left-orderable and contains Thompson's group $F$.